# How to get the difference between two dates in Java including the last day?

Tags: java, date

I'm writing automated bdds for a rest API. And the API returns a date. I want to get the difference between the returned date from the API and the current date today.

So for example, the API returns "March 13, 2018 12:00 pm"

And today's date is "March 11, 2018 12:00pm"

The times are always the same, it's only the days that change. And the API will also return a date that's in the future.

I have this piece of code:

```
Date currentDate = Date.from(Instant.now());
// endDate comes from the API
long diff = endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
long differenceInDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This returns `1`, but I want it to include the last day. I can just add `+1` at the end of `endDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();` but I'm not sure if that's the right approach.

I also read that this is not a good solution in general, because it doesn't account for daylight savings time. I'm not sure how or if it would affect my automated bdds when daylight savings comes. What's the best way to capture the difference in days?

Think of it as `how many days do I have left until expiration`

Comment: I would use the `LocalDate` API which is designed to work in days.

Comment: you can use `android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()` to get the remaining time like `1 Hours/minutes ago`, `yesterday` & `MMM DD, YY` format.

Comment: What are “bdds”?

Comment: You [should use](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) the new Java Date and Time API from the `java.time` package. With the `Period` or `Duration` classes, you can easily calculate the difference, using the `between` method. It takes DST into consideration, when you provide a timezone.

Comment: Using your code, the difference between "March 13, 2018 12:00 pm" and "March 11, 2018 12:00 pm" is exactly 2. How did you get 1?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to round up the number of days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem is that your backend [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service is poorly designed.

## ISO 8601

First of all, date-time values exchanged should be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, not some localized presentation string.

The standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating text.

## java.time

Never use the terrible `Date` class. That class, along with `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such, was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

> Date.from(Instant.now())

Never mix the terrible legacy date-time classes (`Date`) with their replacements (`Instant`), the modern *java.time* classes. Mixing these is unnecessary and confusing.

The *java.time* classes entirely replace their predecessors.

> The times are always the same, it's only the days that change. And the API will also return a date that's in the future.

If you only want to exchange date values, without a time-of-day and without a time zone or offset, use `LocalDate` class, and exchange the ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD such as `2018-03-11`. Call `LocalDate.parse` and `LocalDate::toString`.

> long differenceInDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Representing a count of days as a count of milliseconds without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC is reckless. Days are *not* always 24 hours long. They can be 23, 23.5, 25, or some other number of hours.

If you mean to use UTC so as to always have 24-hour days, say so. Represent your date-time with an indication of time zone or offset. For example, the standard format: `2018-03-11T00:00Z` where the `Z` on the end means UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”.

So your entire problem could be reduced to this one-liner.

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ,  // Get the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
    LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" )                     // Parse a string in standard ISO 8601 format for a date-only value.
)   // Returns a `long` integer number of days elapsed.
```

### Unzoned

If you are not in a position to clean up all those messy design problems, then let's forge ahead, trying to use this messy data.

First fix the `am`/`pm` which should be in uppercase.

```
 String input = "March 13, 2018 12:00 pm".replace( " am" , " AM" ).replace( " pm" , " PM" );
```

Define a formatting pattern to match your input string.

Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to use in translating the text.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMMM d, uuuu HH:mm a" );
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` because your input lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-03-13T12:00

A `LocalDateTime` purposely has no concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this class *cannot* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

If you want generic 24-hour days without regard to the reality of anomalies in wall-clock time used by various people in various places, such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), we can continue to use this class.

Get the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used the people to whom your app is aimed (a time zone).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis()) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Get noon on that date, in no particular time zone.

```
LocalDateTime ldtTodayNoon = LocalDateTime.of( today , LocalTime.NOON ) ;
```

Count days elapsed.

```
long daysElapsed = 
    ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( 
        ldtTodayNoon , 
        ldt 
    )
;
```

Of course we could just as well have done this using only `LocalDate` rather than `LocalDateTime`, but I followed your problem statement as written.

Notice that in your given example, the string represents a date in the past. So our number of days will be negative.

### Zoned

If you did want to account for anomalies seen on some dates in some zones, then you should have represented a moment properly, as discussed above, with an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Or perhaps you want noon today in the desired time zone. If noon is not a valid time-of-day on this date in this zone, the `ZonedDateTime` class will adjust. Be sure to read the [`ZonedDateTime.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalTime,java.time.ZoneId)) JavaDoc to understand the algorithm of that adjustment.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTodayNoon = ZonedDateTime.of( today , LocalTime.NOON , z ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time either based in fractional seconds, or in whole calendar days.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtTodayNoon , zdt ) ;  // For a calculation based in whole seconds plus a fractional second in nanoseconds without regard for a calendar, just using generic 24-hour days.
Period p = Period.between( zdtTodayNoon , zdt ) ;  // For a calculation based in whole days, for a number of years-months-days based on calendar dates.
```

If you insist on tracking by a count of milliseconds, call [`Duration::toMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis()).

```
long millisecondsElapsed = d.toMillis() ;  // Entire duration as a total number of milliseconds, ignoring any microseconds or nanos.
```

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. You can learn more and see more examples by searching for these *java.time* class names.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).